# Android using ION with PhotoView Library

Tags: android, imageview, android-ion, photoviewer

My application keeps crashing every time I try to use the `PhotoViewAttacher` on my application of the `PhotoView` library. I'm using `ION` to display images and trying to get the `PhotoView` library to allow me to zoom into them. My code currently is:

```
public class massiveImageView extends Activity {
    ImageView mImageView;
     PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;
    Drawable drawable;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.massive_image_view);

        // Any implementation of ImageView can be used!
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewMassivePage);



        Ion.with(this).load("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/522909800191901697/FHCGSQg0.png").withBitmap().asBitmap()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, Bitmap result) {
                        // do something with your bitmap
                        drawable=new BitmapDrawable(result);
                        mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                    }
                });

                mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mImageView);

    }
}
```

And the error I'm getting is at this line:

```
mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mImageView);
```

Saying:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't quite understand why it doesn't work, but I was able to find an answer, where instead of adding the dependency of the library, I just found the jar file online and added that instead, now everything is working perfect.
[Library Link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.chrisbanes.photoview/library/1.2.2)